# Set height of div to 0

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following `HTML` code generated dynamically. I need to set the `height` of the `div` that has the height as `34px` to `0px`. Since this `div` does not have a `class` or an `id`, I am unable use any of the DOM manipulation options like `.getElementById()`, `.getElementByClassName`, or `.getElementByTag()`. I need to set the `height` of this `div` to `0` using `JavaScript`.

[image]

**EDIT**

I apologize, I should have asked the question in a better manner, and I should have anticipated, and understood the need in advance before asking the question. This is what I truly need:

```
<div class="fht-cell">
    <div class="filterControl">
        <!-- This should stay as it is. -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fht-cell">
    <div style="height: 34px;">
        <!-- This height should become 0px. -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fht-cell">
    <div class="filterControl">
        <!-- This should stay as it is. -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fht-cell">
    <div style="height: 34px;">
        <!-- This height should become 0px. -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Your answer helped me, but since all the parent `div`s had the class `fht-cell`, and since we had mentioned child `[0]` the height for only the first `div` became `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('fht-cell')[0].children[0]` or similar.

Comment: I apologize. I will add this edit to the question so that you can see it better.

Comment: Hi Steve, I did not anticipate this issue, I have multiple div elements like this: <div class="fht-cell">   <div class="filterControl">        </div> </div> <div class="fht-cell">   <div style="height: 34px;">    </div> </div> <div class="fht-cell">   <div class="filterControl">    </div> </div> <div class="fht-cell">   <div style="height: 34px;">    </div> </div> In this case, I want to get all the div elements who have height of 34px and reduce that to 0. You see, not all divs have the height mentioned. –

Comment: I can manually add children numbers to get other columns, like column 1 and 3, and then set the size accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

first-child selector should do the trick.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp